# Loop count in dataframe

Tags: r

For this dataset, df2 I have subsetted it to the 3 columns (id, frame and xVelocity). In order to apply some clustering techniques (later on) I need to change the frame values (second column) such that for every new id the frame will start at 1. This is because many of the frames start at random numbers for new id's.

[Image of dataframe df2. The value circled in red would ideally be 1 and then count up until the next id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rImiY.png)

I am thinking a while loop would be the best idea through the dataframe which counts for every new row until a new id value is reached?

Any further ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

CSV File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tMOz_yM-WenSOlF3UK6UatniwtFI7kzf/view?usp=sharing

```
 #This programme clusters vehicles based on their driving style

library(ggplot2)
library(fpc)
library(factoextra)
library(readr)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(fpp2)
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
library(dtw)

#Clear all variables in workspace
rm(list=ls())

#Importing data
df <- read_csv("01_tracks.csv")

# #Spreading out id's into seperate columns
# id.spread <- spread(df,id,x)

#Filtering data to just 3 columns
df1 <- filter(df,laneId == 5, width <= 6) #Filtering to lane 5, no trucks
df2 <- select(df1,id,frame,xVelocity)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

`df2 <- select(df1,id,frame,xVelocity) %>% group_by(df1, id, xVelocity) %>% mutate(frame = row_number())`

or, if you don't need df1 column:

`df2 <- select(df1,id,frame,xVelocity) %>% group_by(id, xVelocity) %>% mutate(frame = row_number())`

Comment: Thankyou. This does reset the frame to 1 for each new id but unfortunately, this doesn't quite count up the frames for each id